# mvc application restart automatically after one scenario, which not throw an error or so

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I doing some steps, and after it my application restart automatically. How does it possible?
Please, could anyone advice something for debug that staff and understand - what is the reason of such a strange behaviour.

The are no exception, logs are clear. Application use autofac for DI. Please feel free to ask me any additional question. It's extremely important for me to solve that issue. thanks a lot.

**UPD:** problem caused by this method. If I delete it - all works fine.

```
public void DeleteUserPreviewDir()
{
    string path = GetUserPreviewDir();
    Action<string> del = null;
    del = s => {
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(s);
                    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(s);

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Delete(file);
                    }

                    foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    {
                        del(dir);
                    }

                    Directory.Delete(s, false);
              };
    del(path);
}
```

But UserPreviewDir placed under root web folder, not in bin folder. File structure is the following: root\tempfiles\folder_which_delete 
Bin dir placed in root\bin

Comment: When you say it restarts, what do you mean? How do you know it's restarted? What symptoms do you experience that let you know something has happened?

Comment: Add more information please. What steps do you perform? Is it a specific step that after that your application is restarting?

Comment: If you are also updating the web.config file then this is why it is restarting.

Comment: Sounds like you are deleting something under the `bin` directory.

Comment: I update question, could you take a look. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of such behavior is that i'm delete site subfolder. Why application recycle - this is still unknown.

Answer (score 2):

There are different causes why an ASP.NET application could restart:

- After a certain period of inactivity IIS could simply recycle the application pool (this period is configurable in the properties of the application pool)
- Your application reaches a certain threshold of memory or CPU usage and IIS will recycle it (those thresholds are configurable in IIS)
- You have updated `web.config` or some of the assemblies situated in the `bin` folder (added an assembly, updated an existing assembly, removed an assembly).
- You have updated the `Global.asax` file in the root folder.

Comment: So you are deleting something from the `~/bin` folder?

Comment: No. i delete root subfolder, but not bin subfolder

Comment: What's inside this subfolder? Are there some assemblies that you might have loaded into the AppDomain?

Comment: I create more detailed question. please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413092/iis-restart-mvc3-application-when-delete-subdir

Comment: Deleting a folder containing only jpg files should not be the cause for restarting the AppDomain. It sounds like you are deleting some other folder containing assemblies that have been loaded into this AppDomain. There's not much you could do to prevent this from happening. It's how ASP.NET works.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it so. I'll try to debug it step bu step and it delete only user folder and after that appdomain restart. And if comment deleting method, all works as should.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue, in order to find out the reason of restart you can use following code (just put it into Global.asax.cs and change `m_logger.Fatal` to whatever you using for logging):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null);

    if (runtime == null)
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField;
        string shutDownMessage = (string) runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage",
            bindingFlags,
            null,
            runtime,
            null);
        string shutDownStack = (string) runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack",
            bindingFlags,
            null,
            runtime,
            null);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(shutDownMessage))
            m_logger.Fatal(String.Format("_shutDownMessage={0}\r\n\r\n_shutDownStack={1}", shutDownMessage, shutDownStack));
    }
}
```