# IIS restart MVC3 application when delete subdir

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have directory with following structure

```
root
     temp
        User_related_folder
          preview1.jpg
          preview2.jpg
          preview3.jpg
```

I need to delete User_related_folder when user logout. But when i do that my application restart. Why does it happend and is it possible to fix that?

My application working under aplication pool with .net 4.0 in integrated mode. I try SystemNetwork and local system credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still no correct answer. For now i just delete all files from subdir and do not delete subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

That is the way IIS works.  When you fiddle with the directory structure you get a recycle for your efforts.

To solve this use a folder *outside* of the site structure to store temporary/working folders.

Comment: The rules for this changed in .Net 4.0 (see the comment here from Microsoft http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646824/asp-net-application-restart-ignore-folder-setting) so are not as restrictive

Comment: can't you use App_Data folder for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Any changes to the bin folder will restart the app. Same as changing anything in we.config.

Answer (score 0):

the msdn said,if you delete files in /bin/,or delete any directory under application,the app will be restart.

so,if you have to delete under the application folder,you have to restart application.

or you can change the del's dir out of application virtual path,but it's will be trigger security questions.

at last I suggest you delete the files under the directory,don't delete the directory.

Answer (score 0):

uploading/deleting things to the App_data folder will bypass this issue.